# C# Creating generic List from JArray

Tags: c#, json, generics

I'm working on a dynamic import proces from Json to object array.
Getting a little bit stuck by creating a List<> based on a string reference to the class object.

I'm importing json data from a REST server and using a business objects list to map the json data to predefined classes that can be configured. I'm using NewtonSoft.Json for the parsing of the data to classes.

```
string classname = "BusinessObjects.Contact";
Type classtype = Type.GetType(classname);
// ... filled jsonstring from api request
string json = "[]"; // json filled from rest request
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
JArray array = (JArray)obj["contacts"];

// the issue part...
var records = array.ToObject<List<classtype>>();
```

The compiler states I'm using a variable as a type. Which makes sense, but can't find a way around it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `array.ToObject<List<BusinessObjects.Contact>>();`

Comment: That would work off course, but the point is that it's generic. the "classname" as string comes from the database as a mapping configuration. I don't know the class type at forehand. The question is about creating the List<> from a string typed representation of the class name and letting the NewtonSoft work it's magic deserializing the json to a class.

Comment: So you already have the *JArray* array. When everything is dynamic you can not use concrete classes. Take your values from that array *dynamically*. Every value you need is in that object

Comment: No, I have the JSON array and like to dynamically deserialize it with a generic type my code doesn't know at forehand and which is not hard-coded.

Comment: `my code doesn't know at forehand and which is not hard-coded` I don't see where do we disagree. You can not use a concrete object here. You will have to use some *ints* or *strings* to get that value like `array[someint]["someprop"]`. If you cast it to a concrete type, then you will have to use *reflection* . Same problem. How about posting a *real* problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than deserializing your `JArray`, you could access it dynamically as shown in [Querying JSON with dynamic](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm).  But if you would prefer to deserialize to a fixed list type, since you are writing non-generic reflection-based code, you can do:

```
var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(classtype);
var records = array.ToObject(listType);
```

Notes:

- Given an open generic type such as `List<>`, [`Type.MakeGenericType()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype(v=vs.110).aspx) creates a closed generic type by substituting the `Type` argument(s) for the type parameters of the open type.
- [`JToken.ToObject()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject.htm) is a non-generic version of `ToObject()` that can deserialize to a specified `Type`.
- Once you have created your `records` list you can cast it to the non-generic `IList` interface to access collections items.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WjNbBZ) with prototype sample JSON and definition for `BusinessObjects.Contact`.

Comment: Since you don't know the type of `records` at compile time, you can not use a stmt like `records[0].Id`. So Why to do all these things. JArray already have methods/properties to get values from it (`array[inx][propName]`).

Comment: Thanks. I suspect classtype parameter in MakeGenericType() needs to be casted to Type.GetType(classname) first.  But gor the same compiler error as before. in the second line of your code  var records = array.ToObject<listType>(); states that listType is a variable but is used like a type.

Comment: @L.B - The question doesn't have much detail, but possibilities include 1) Deserializing to a one of several fixed types would allow access to instance methods to, say, calculate nontrivial derived values (mass, volume, cost, whatever).  2) Deserializing to a fixed type then reserializing could standardize the schema of the resulting output.  3) Deserializing to a fixed type then reserializing could be required to invoke certain converters to perform certain transformations.

Comment: @Blazar - sorry, that's what I get for trying to write code without a compilable [mcve] to test.